# Servlet gets parameter of HTML select

Tags: html, jsp, servlets

This will sound stupid a bit, but I'm so confused about it!
I'm trying to get the posted parameters from the request, and I have two elements in my html form from the type  as follow:

```
<select id="mapped_fields" name="mapped_fields_name" multiple style="width: 150px;">
 .
 .
 .
 .
 options ..
</select>
```

I'm trying to do the following in my servlet:

```
String[] values = request.getParameterValues("mapped_fields");
```

this line returns null! I tried to change the select in the html and deleted the

```
multiple
```

and my line returned the correct value!
When I try to debug the following line:

I got the following result (all my fields except the select):

> {action=[Ljava.lang.String;@3a1ceae6,
>   campaign=[Ljava.lang.String;@4081bfd8}

Any Idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to give `name` attribute to `select`

```
<select name = "mapped_fields" id="mapped_fields" multiple="multiple" style="width: 150px;">
 <option value="1">option1</option>
 <option value="2">option2</option>
 <option value="3">option3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: @MarwanJaber : What is in the array `values`?

Comment: the problem was in the javascript generates the element, it was missing up with the tag, so yes it is working now and i took your advices in this solution, mucho gracias :)

Answer (score 3):

You must replace `id="mapped_fields"` by `name="mapped_fields"`.

Also, `<option value="1">option1` is invalid, you should use like this :

```
<option value="1">option1</option>
```

Comment: thanks for this, it helped with another problem i had :) but not in the current one, it still not working!

Comment: @MarwanJaber You probably should edit your question including the form + working fields. Also the code you are using to print all received values. Currently, the line `request.getParameterValues("mapped_fields");` doesn't have the same `name` as provided in your HTML code.

Comment: Actually i tried again, and it seems like the javascipt generates this element was not adding the closing tag. so yes it is working now, thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

To select **multiple** values,
            Try this,

```
          <select name = "mapped_fields" multiple id="mapped_fields"  style="width: 150px;">
            <option value="1">option1</option>
            <option value="2">option2</option>
            <option value="3">option3</option>
          </select>
```

> **multiple Instead of "multiple"**

Hope it helps! Kindly inform me if it works

Comment: Thanks for trying, it is the same for both :)